# Что за объект получается на выходе функции window.jQuery() и куда этот объект "прикреплен" в BOM?

Tags: jquery

Привет.

Вопрос по jQuery.

1. Что за объект получается на выходе функции `window.jQuery()` и куда этот объект "прикреплен" в BOM ?
2. Почему не используется ключевое слово new? Насколько я знаю, только функция-конструктор может создать объект. А `window.jQuery()` как раз это и делает - создает объект. В книге Флэнагана написано по этому поводу, что "jQuery() является фабричной функцией, а не конструктором: она возвращает вновь созданный объект, но она используется без ключевого слова new" . Что значит "фабричной" функцией? Первый раз такой термин вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На выходе *window.jQuery()* получается обычный javascript объект. Он никуда не прикреплен. Сохранить его можно в любой переменной, либо передать в качестве параметра.

> Почему не используется ключевое слово new?

Потому что jQuery - это обычная функция, а не конструктор.

[Фабричная функция, так же известна под названием Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Чтобы разобраться, что же происходит в функции jQuery, можно обратится напрямую к исходникам, и там можно увидеть [следующее](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery)

```
function (selector, context) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context);
}
```

Отсюда видно, что данная функция используется просто для вызова конструктора, поэтому нет нужды использовать оператор `new`

Answer (score 2):

Согласно докам, аргументом может быть строка, DOM объект, коллекция DOM, js объект, jquery объект либо ничего.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/